# Can the iPhone camera detect flashing? (as in a flashing image?)

Tags: camera, ios6

Can the iPhone camera detect flashing? (as in a flashing image?) I am looking to get some help with this, fairly new to the whole x code world so any advice you can give would be greatly appreciated.